# Creating Pages with my Custom CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have started creating a CMS today for my own personal use, for management purporses and also to teach myself a few things.

I have a section in my admin area where I can create/update/delete pages or posts which works great.

My question is how do I generate pages, and URL's from the information I have stored in my database?

Let's say for example my table "posts" has a few rows which contain "post_title", "post_content", "post_slug", etc. How do I generate a page from this information in my database (because it's obviously not creating pages based on PHP files), so I would have http://mywebsite.com/cool-new-post-slug.php (then I can get content by ID, etc)?

If someone can point me in the right direction that would be great. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I saw one time that a system was generating a URL in the POST row (it had a URL column) and when you try to enter something that does not existe, you try to find that URL in the column, if it matchs, it gives all info about that POST and you should render it. Remember that if you follow this, when you update your POST, if the title was edited you have to remake the URL.

Comment: I think its easier to have a 'title' column in your posts table and use the title as urls instead of creating new file each time a post is created.

Comment: Don't mean this in a rude way, but if you built the CRUD section of your program you should know how to retrieve the data.  Read up on using GET variables. You'll want to do something like mywebsite.com/page.php?slug=cool-new-post.  Or take it a step further and learn about mod_rewrite and then you can just do mywebsite.com/cool-new-post/

Comment: I understand how to retrieve the data, what I am not sure about is how to generate a page URL from information in the database? So that I would be able to navigate to the slug (then I can get the content for the page/post, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you'll need to retrieve all the slugs from the database first, then use them to construct your url.

Assuming you're using mysqli:

```
$query = "SELECT post_slug,post_title FROM posts";
$posts = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($post = mysqli_fetch_assoc($posts)){

    echo "<a href=\"single.php?slug=" . $post["post_slug"] . "\">";
    echo $post["post_title"];
    echo "</a><br/>";

}

mysqli_free_result($posts);
```

Then on `single.php` you'll use the GET variable `post_slug` to retrieve your data.

in your .htaccess file you can use mod_rewrite to get pretty URLS as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule posts/(.+?)/?$ single.php?slug=$1
```

this would show the url `http://mywebsite.com/posts/cool-new-post/` your browser, but what it will really be accessing is `single.php?slug=cool-new-post`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I realized what I am asking does not make a whole lot of sense.. What I am really trying to do now is change my URL http://localhost/cms/single.php?id=1 to something more pleasant. So I am looking into pretty URL's through .htaccess.. but have all the content for each post on it's own page :) thanks

Comment: Then you definitely need to look into mod_rewrite.  You can still have only the single.php to process and display each page but give each one its own pretty URL.

Comment: Cool thanks so much! That's what I was looking for, mod rewrites - cheers!